# Which OS printer driver am I supposed to install on 2008 32-bit server to share with Win 7 x64 clients?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7

Am I supposed to install Microsoft Windows Server 2008 x64 printer drivers on my 2008 32-bit server to support Windows 7 x64 clients while supporting Windows XP 32-bit clients?

I have a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard (not R2) 32-bit server with the Print Services role. I have mostly 32-bit XP clients that are able to print to the server's shared printers. We're getting Windows 7 Pro x64 workstations coming in and I want to share the same printers from the same server with those new workstations.

The printers I'm most concerned about are HP LaserJet P4014ns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes.

**Longer answer:** You need to install two *sets* of drivers.

1. Drivers for the *print server itself*:  Use whatever drivers are available/compatible with the print server's own architecture to actually install the printer on the server.
2. Drivers for the *clients* that are printing via the print server: In this case both Windows 7 x64 drivers and drivers for 32-bit XP. If you're looking at the printer's properties tab on the server, these are installed via the 'Additional Drivers' button.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the HP Universal Print Driver PCL 6 for Windows 2008 W32. The I downloaded the HP Universal Printer Driver PCL 6 for Windows 7 x64. They both have the same version number. I added the x64 driver to the Windows 2008 server from the Windows 7 computer. The printers are using the new driver now. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the "Windows cannot connect to the printer" message (hadn't mentioned that) but at least I know the version of the drivers are the same. Thanks.